# Value combinations of n subarrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, combinations, cartesian-product

I want to create a Java method, which accepts an `inputArray = Object[n][]`, where n can be any integer, and outputs a list of possible n-size combinations between all values of the n subarrays. Below is an example:

Input Array: (where Object=String and n=3)

```
String[] subarrayA = {"A0","A1","A2"};
String[] subarrayB = {"B0","B1"};
String[] subarrayC = {"C0","C1","C2","C3"};
String[3][] inputArray = {subarrayA, subarrayB, subarrayC};
```

Desired Output:

```
{A0,B0,C0},{A0,B0,C1},{A0,B0,C2},{A0,B0,C3},
{A0,B1,C0},{A0,B1,C1},{A0,B1,C2},{A0,B1,C3},
{A1,B0,C0},{A1,B0,C1},{A0,B0,C2},{A1,B0,C3},
{A1,B1,C0},{A1,B1,C1},{A1,B1,C2},{A1,B1,C3},
{A2,B0,C0},{A2,B0,C1},{A2,B0,C2},{A2,B0,C3},
{A2,B1,C0},{A2,B1,C1},{A2,B1,C2},{A2,B1,C3}
```

Obviously, I cannot have a fixed nested-loop inside my method since I do not know `n` in advance. So, I am guessing the only way to solve it would be through a recursive method? Any recommendations?

P.S: I am aware of the simple [combination-related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) on the website.

Comment: Is this a homework? What did you try?

Comment: No, this is not a homework. I am trying to create a prior probability table for my Bayesian network, based on a dataset that only has 'categorical' columns. I need the combinations to create SQL queries with the given column values on the fly.

Comment: In proper mathematical terms, the desired output is the *cartesian product* of the n input sets. ("n-size combinations between all values of the n subarrays" would probably include {A0,A1,B0}, too.)

Comment: @Scorpion do you have answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
public static void permute(String array[][], int index, ArrayList<String> output){

    if(index == array.length){
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0 ; i<array[index].length ; i++){
            output.add(array[index][i]);
            permute(array,index+1,output);
            output.remove(output.size() - 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much fro your help. I am not a programmer by training and find recursion quite unintuitive, i.e. hard.

Comment: is this complexity dependent on the r in nCr?

Comment: @JProgrammer Can you explain how this works. I don't understand how `output.remove(output.size() - 1);` is ever executed if it is after you call `permute(array,index+1,output);`. Wouldn't calling `permute()` cause `output.remove()` to never be called?

Comment: This is difficult to explain in words. 'if(index == array.length)' will prevent calling permute eventually. I am pretty sure that there are animation to demonstrate how this exactly works.

Comment: Every function call will return to the point it is called and continue executing after, even successive recursive calls.  Use a stack and trace the calls out on paper.  Notice what happens when if(index == array.length) is true.  The sequence is printed.  When it returns at that point it continues after the recursive call removing the last string and continuing the for loop to output the next permutation.